# Reading Binary/Byte from SQL on C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, byte, datarow

Im trying to read the Binary Data of the Document Stored on SQL.

But when im suppose to store it in my Template Class i can't.

```
presentation.presentationDocBinData = byte.Parse(dr["presentationDocBinData"].ToString());

public byte[] presentationDocBinData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

So im reading it from a DataRow. I tried byte[], Byte, byte, Byte[]. Im pretty lost on what to do.. any enlightment would be much appreciated.

Comment: What if you remove .ToString() and cast to byte array?

Comment: @Uriil you meant it this way ? **byte[].Parse(dr["presentationDocBinData"]);**

it says "invalid expression term 'byte'.

Comment: (Byte[])dr["presentationDocBigData"]

Comment: @Uriil WOW That works, thanks!!! Was looking for some clue.. but can't find any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply cast object to byte array:

```
 var result = (Byte[])dr["presentationDocBigData"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it in `byte[]`(byte array)

```
presentation.presentationDocBinData = (byte[])dr["presentationDocBinData"];

public byte[] presentationDocBinData
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

`byte.Parse()` converts only single value into byte. for example if you have a value like `"A"` and you want to convert it into `byte` then you can use `byte.Parse()` method to convert value into `byte`.